# Detecting clicks outside an element with 'on' event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to detect clicks outside the element with id 'proplist'. However, I already have an 'on' event function that detects value changes of an input. I tried to access the form-key value from the mouseup event, but I it didn't return any data. How can I get the value of form-key after detecting clicks outside the element?

```
  $('#plusData').on("blur", "input[id^=form-key]", function(){
    console.log($(this).val());

    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest("#proplist").length === 0 ) {
            console.log($(this).val());
        }
    });

});
```

html code

```
    <div id="proplist">
    <div id="plusData">
        <div class="form-group form-group-extraData" id="box" style="width: 100%;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-key1" name="key" >
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-content1" name="content" >
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-alt-primary" value="+" onclick="addTextbox()">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you **can't** really modify the outside element from a css selector.

But you can just add another event listener for the parent of this element, or add such wrapper for that. CSS pseudo selector `:has()` maybe a way out for this.

For example, I made 2 wrappers in the snippet below, one has a child `#proplist` and the other one doesn't.

```js
$('.wrapper:has(#proplist)').click(e => {
  console.log(e.target.classList.value);
  e.target.classList.toggle('red');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background: none;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.wrapper.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="proplist">
      <div id="plusData">
          <div class="form-group form-group-extraData" id="box" style="width: 100%;">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-key1" name="key" >
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-content1" name="content" >
              <input type="button" class="btn btn-alt-primary" value="+" onclick="addTextbox()">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Not having proplist</h1>
</div>
```